# How can i set z-index in Plotly rangeslider

Tags: plotly, rangeslider

I have been trying to make rangeslider that displays two graphs(trace) which share x axis
but I got a problem.
Second graph (bar graph) cover first graph, so first graph become totally invisible

To solve this problem,
I think, i need something like z-index of css.
but, i wasn't able to find this in Plotly DOC.

How can i change order of display in rangeslider?

Comment: **plotly** doesn't really have a z-index.  It's really just down to order traces are in figure and a few other rules.  Consider re-ordering traces `fig.data = fig.data[::-1]`

Comment: @RobRaymond    
I changed order of fig.data with your method.. but it's not working..

Comment: provide a MWE and I'll look into it.  as noted it's not just the order of traces it is the trace type as well

Comment: @RobRaymond fig.data = (Candlestick({...}), Scatter({...}), Bar({...})) => fig.data is structured like this..